# ManageEngine to Sharepoint authentication 401 NTLM

Tags: java, authentication, sharepoint, curl, sharepoint-2010

I need some help on a Java application.
This code is from ManageEngine and is a sample with integration to Jira.

I need to integrate with Sharepoint but I have difficulties getting access to Sharepoint and is getting

> 'unauthorized:You are not authenticated. Authentication required to
>    perform this operation'
>
> - which is error 401.

I got a curl script to test access and this is only working with NTLM authentication - but this sample is build for BASIC authentication.

Could some please help on how to convert this authentication in this script to use NTLM - I have spent days reading about this, but I'm very new to Java, so I'm really stocked right now.

I believe the issue is this part of the code (full code is to big to present):

```
 private String getResultantFromExtApp(String requestURL, String methodType, String data, HashMap authenticationDetails) throws Exception {

    String resultant = null;
    String userName = (String) authenticationDetails.get("username");
    String passWord = (String) authenticationDetails.get("password");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "requestURL:::::::::" + requestURL);
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();

        String userpassword = userName + ":" + passWord;
        String encodedAuthorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userpassword.getBytes());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        if (methodType.equals("POST"))
        {
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // No I18N
        }
        else if (methodType.equals("GET"))
        {
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // No I18N
        }

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // No I18N
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization); // No I18N
        if (methodType.equals("POST"))
        {
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
            Writer write = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"); // No I18N
            write.write(data);
            write.close();
            out.close();
        }
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "responseCode:::::::::" + responseCode);
        InputStream content = null;
```